Laravel page not loading
I'm completely new to laravel and learning from a course.
Literally just started creating a project same way in the tutorial, the tutorial goes to the laravel welcome page when artisan serve ran but mine gives me
In my terminal I wrote "composer create-project laravel/laravel myProjectName"
Then wrote "php artisan serve"
I expected to see a welcome page in the browser but instead got an error

could not find driver(connection:sqlite:SQL:PRAGMA foreign-keys=on;)


As you might not be the first person facing such an error: did you try to use your favorite search engine to find possible solutions? Did you try anything to resolve the problem?

As we speaking I'm busy searching for solutions and nothing yet

Does this answer your question? Laravel: PDOException: could not find driver

It's probably the problem of an extension not activated on php.ini
You should go to your php.ini commonly C:\php\php.ini on windows or /etc/php/php.ini on linux and edit the file
you should remove the semicolon at extension=pdo_sqlite , extension=pdo_mysql or
extension=mysqli depending on what database are you running your app on.
Enable them (again, by removing the semicolon) and see if this works.
